# Finite index subgroup of congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0(4)$ and $\Gamma$

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, modular-group

It is standard notation  but I define them anyway to avoid ambiguity: $$\Gamma_0(N) := \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 
                 c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma : c \equiv 0 \text{(mod $N$)}\right\}$$ and $$\Gamma:=SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$$

With this notation I'm trying to figure out what the subgroups of finite index of $\Gamma_0(4)$ and $\Gamma$ are. In particular, given $\Gamma'$ a subgroup of $\Gamma_0(4)$ of finite index I have to prove that  $\Gamma' \cap \left\{ \pm \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & j \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} , j\in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$ is of the form $\left\{\pm\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & h \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^j , j\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ for $h>0$

- Is there a direct way to see this?
- Are finite index subgroups simply subgroups $\Gamma_0(4N)$ or are they something more general?

Comment: You don't need to know the finite index subgroups of $\Gamma_0(4)$ for this question.

Comment: @AlexB. I'm still missing the point: the fact that I don't need to know what those subgroups are, makes the problem even less clear to me.

Comment: Show that the intersection with that other subgroup, $\pm\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&\mathbb{Z}\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, has finite index in that subgroup; then think about what the subgroups of *that* group look like.